# Changing colors and representing different values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make a graph in ggplot and I have been running into a couple problems...

So, here's a sample of my data:

```
      SAT     GPA Tutor1 Tutor2  ESL     Sex   Aid Race   Tutor_
1    1010    3.69      1      1   No       M     1    1    1
2     670    2.82      0      0   Yes      M     0    1    0
3    1120    3.95      0      1   No       F     1    2    1
4    1230    3.51      1      0   Yes      F     1    1    1
5    1340    4.42      0      1   No       F     0    1    1
6    1200    2.99      0      0   No       F     0    1    0
7    1090    4.01      0      1   No       M     1    1    1
8     710    2.90      1      0   No       F     1    1    1
9    1060    3.67      1      0   No       F     1    2    1
10   1150    3.91      1      1   No       F     1    1    1
```

Ultimately, I am trying to create a scatterplot which shows GPA (on x-axis) versus SAT (on y-axis) by the variable 'Tutor_', with 0 values in purple and 1 values in red. I'd like to have a legend on the right which shows 'as.factor(Tutor_)' and both values, and two regression lines (one for 0 and another for 1), with confidence intervals for each.

Here's what I've tried so far. I still need to separate the values for the variable 'Tutor_' so they're not all the same color.

```
mytheme <- theme(legend.position="right", plot.title = element_text(size = (12), hjust = 0.5), axis.title = element_text(size = (12)))

ggplot(data = mydata, mapping = aes(x = GPA, y = SAT)) + 
      geom_point(aes(x = GPA, y = SAT)) +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
      ggtitle("Tutoring: SAT and GPA") +
      mytheme
```

I'd also like to know how to create a subtitle which can be placed directly below the title. Any contributions to the various aspects of this question are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
  Row  SAT     GPA Tutor1 Tutor2  ESL     Sex   Aid Race   Tutor_
  1    1010    3.69      1      1   No       M     1    1    1
  2     670    2.82      0      0   Yes      M     0    1    0
  3    1120    3.95      0      1   No       F     1    2    1
  4    1230    3.51      1      0   Yes      F     1    1    1
  5    1340    4.42      0      1   No       F     0    1    1
  6    1200    2.99      0      0   No       F     0    1    0
  7    1090    4.01      0      1   No       M     1    1    1
  8     710    2.90      1      0   No       F     1    1    1
  9    1060    3.67      1      0   No       F     1    2    1
  10   1150    3.91      1      1   No       F     1    1    1"
  ) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Tutor_ = Tutor_ %>% fct_inorder())

mytheme <- theme(
  legend.position="right", 
  plot.title = element_text(size = (12), hjust = 0.5), 
  axis.title = element_text(size = (12)))

mydata %>% ggplot(aes(GPA, SAT, color = Tutor_)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = 'y ~ x', method = "lm") +
  ggtitle("Tutoring: SAT and GPA") +
  mytheme
```

[image]

A few closing remarks.

1. The chart was created on the basis of the data you published.
2. The key mutation is `mutate(Tutor_ = Tutor_%>% fct_inorder())`
3. The `aes` in `ggplot` must receive the color information `color = Tutor_`.
4. In `geom_point`, you don't need to set aesthetics a second time.
5. Use the `dput` function when publishing data in the future. For example, `dput(mydata)` and publish what the function returns.